# How to solve invalid column name error when create stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I write below stored procedure but get error that :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GetAvailableSensor, Line 7
>
> Invalid column name 'SuctionWater1'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>
> Procedure sp_GetAvailableSensor, Line 8 Invalid column name
>
> 'SuctionWater2'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>
> sp_GetAvailableSensor, Line 11 Invalid column name 'SuctionPresure1'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GetAvailableSensor, Line 12
>
> Invalid column name 'SuctionPresure2'.

```
    USE [SpmsTwoSuctionOneThrust]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAvailableSensor]
AS
BEGIN
    
    SELECT TOP 1 [Id],
           [PowerControl],
           [SuctionWater1],
           [SuctionWater2],
           [InundationWater],
           [EvacuationWater],
           [SuctionPresure1],
           [SuctionPresure2],
           [ThrustPressure]
    FROM   [SPMS].[dbo].[AvailableSensor]
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the table from the different database, from `SPMS`:

```
FROM   [SPMS].[dbo].[AvailableSensor]
```

While the stored procedure and the table schema shown are in `SpmsTwoSuctionOneThrust`:

```
USE [SpmsTwoSuctionOneThrust]
```

The tables schema may differ between two databases.